# How to enable inbuilt wifi and bluetooth in laptop in ubuntu 20.4?

Tags: wireless

I have installed ubuntu in my laptop.But Iam unable to Activate the inbuilt wifi adapter and bluetooth .Please help me to active inbuilt wifi and bluetooth in my laptop.

Comment: What is the make and model of the wireless adapter?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.